# Redirect after login using passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an aplication where i used react and node js. Also i want to create  authentification feature. Register page is working ok, i can get data in node js from fron end. But appears a problem when i try to log in. For log in, in node js, i use passport.js:

```js
app.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, passport.authenticate('local', {  
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true
}
));
```

Also i have the Login component in reactjs:

```js
const Login = () => {
    const [name, setName] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const nameChange = (e) => {
        const val = e.target.value;
        setName(val)
    }
    const passwordChange = (e) => {
        const val = e.target.value;
        setPassword(val)
    }
    const register = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('login: ' + name + password)
        const data = {
            name: name,
            password: password
        };
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },

            body: JSON.stringify( {name:name,password: password})
        };
        fetch('http://localhost:4000/login', requestOptions)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((messages) => {console.log(messages);});
    }
    return (
        < div>
            <h1>Login</h1>
            <form onSubmit={register}>
                <input value={name} onChange={nameChange} type="text" placeholder='name' name='name'/>
                <input value={password} onChange={passwordChange} type="text" placeholder='password' name='password'/>
                <input type="submit" value='Login'/>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
        ;
};

export default Login;
```

The question is, how to connect front end with node js? How to check when the user is loged with success?

Answer (score 0):

You can use session, something like `redis` to store user's information in server-side and set a cookie in your client side.

In this way, you should generate a random key and store user's data in redis with that.

```
'hashed-key' : {//user info in redis}
```

On every request to server, your client side app send the hash-key with cookie, Nodejs app will check the redis for existence of that key and if everything is **OK**, it will process the request.

In client side you create a state for your app: `member` or `visitor`.

It is a good document for the whole idea ["Managing Node.js - Express Sessions with Redis"](https://medium.com/mtholla/managing-node-js-express-sessions-with-redis-94cd099d6f2f)

It is ["Create basic login forms using create react app module in reactjs"](https://medium.com/technoetics/create-basic-login-forms-using-create-react-app-module-in-reactjs-511b9790dede)

And also read ["All You Need to Know About User Session Security"](https://dzone.com/articles/all-you-need-to-know-about-user-session-security)

Comment: i reproduced the code in a condesanbox, could you take a look, please.  https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-chatterjee-nflvz?file=/server/passport-config.js  . Now when i try to login, i get Null in node.js server.

Comment: which function? @Asking

Comment: @SaeedAtaee, what do you mean?

Comment: where do you get `null` in server?? @Asking

Comment: Ataee, here: app.post("/login", checkNotAuthenticated, async (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user) => {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    req.login(user, loginErr => {
      if (loginErr) {
        console.error(err);
      }
      return res.json(user);
    });
  })(req, res);
});

Comment: `res.json(user);` returns null and no **error** logs in `if(loginErr) { console.error(err);` or `if (err) console.error(err);`  statements. Am I right?

Comment: Ok, you have an implementation problem in passport and I can't find that from reading code. I should run and debug It myself. I am not able to do this right now.

Comment: thank you. PLease, let me know when you will have a result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211571/discussion-between-saeed-ataee-and-asking).

Answer (score 0):

If you use Express server with ReactJS, you don't have to use redirect option when call passport.authenticate.

Because each environment is different.

So if you redirect to "/" in Express, it will be redirect app.get("/)

you can try like this

```
app.post('/login', checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user) => {
        if(err) console.error(err);

        req.login(user, loginErr => {
            if(loginErr) {
                console.error(err);
            }

            return res.json(user);
        });
    })(req, res);
});
```

Then, request from React !

```
fetch('http://localhost:4000/login', requestOptions)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((user) => { console.log(user); }); // <- Now you get a user!
    .catch(err => console.error(err)); // <- If failed login
```

if you want to route whether user logged in

try like this

```
const Router = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    // when login request success, setUser(user);


    return user ? <Main /> : <Login />;
}
```

Comment: i reproduced the code in a condesanbox, could you take a look, please.  https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-chatterjee-nflvz?file=/server/passport-config.js  . Now when i try to login, i get Null in node.js server.